# Does MS provide some way for user to manage input bindings?

Tags: wpf

What I mean is as user I would like to change some gestures from ones set by developer. So as developer what should I do to provide this functionality? Does MS provide any extension points for this? If anybody read about it implemented anywhere, please share.

Comment: Could you please be more clear about what you want? You gave examples that are about Visual Studio, but you have tagged this question with "WPF".

Comment: The example is not about Visual Studio. It just happens that I offered this example because I'm writing an IDE. I'll try to state what I want one more time. 
I want user to be able to change input gestures through settings dialog. I'm trying out different ways to do it with no luck for now

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method_editor)?

---

Then you need to use the [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) you have a (somewhat) ready to use [solution](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfCommandPatternApplied.aspx) if you are using WPF.

Comment: No, I'm talking about changing default shortcuts. For example if I specify "F8" as default shortcut for "Build solution", but user would like to change it to "Ctrl+Shift+B". 

Anything will help: blog posts, examples with good implementation, just ideas... anything

Comment: I don't like this solution. He breaks what WPF framework provides and introduces his own methodology. In WPF routed command shouldn't have a context. Command binding is command context

Answer (score 0):

You could use InputBindings and search for a binding using the gesture you want to replace, then remove it and put in your InputBinding instead.

Comment: And if two controls have input bindings with same input gesture but calling different commands. Your way doesn't allow to modify these bindings separately. It also doesn't allow to set more than one gesture.